# How to fix the " unexpected token ']' " error in python3,django2?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add the module to urls.py.
Here's the code:

```py
"""
Definition of urls for learning_log.
"""

from datetime import datetime
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
from app import forms, views
#added
from django.conf.urls import include, url
import learning_logs.views
from django.urls import path,re_path

app_name='learning_logs'
urlpatterns =[
    #added
    path('', include('learning_logs/urls',namespace='learning_logs'),

    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('login/',
         LoginView.as_view
         (
             template_name='app/login.html',
             authentication_form=forms.BootstrapAuthenticationForm,
             extra_context=
             {
                 'title': 'Log in',
                 'year' : datetime.now().year,
             }
         ),
         name='login'),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(next_page='/'), name='logout'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)]
```

The code seems alright,but Visual Studio keeps reporting error:

unexpected token ']'

It says the last ']' has some problem.But it is part of the grammar.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the include learning_logs line:

```py
path('', include('learning_logs/urls',namespace='learning_logs'),
```

should be:

```py
path('', include('learning_logs/urls',namespace='learning_logs')),
```